# Firebase authentication (Google Sign-in) across multiple activities

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to use Firebase for Google authentication in my Android mobile application. I found out a tutorial where both the sign in and sign out features are implemented in same activity. Can someone help in letting me know how to implement the same across multiple activities, like is passing Firebase reference possible?

Answer (score 0):

Fastest would be to implement the logic in the `Application` class and use it whenever you need it